# How to pose a rigged model in Blender 2.72

Tags: pose-mode

Hi I'm new to Blender and I am having problems with a rig I downloaded online. When I import the Blender file I get a static pose and when I attempt to move it nothing happens. I have *Rigify* and *Auto Run Python Scripts* running. Do I need to update to the latest Blender version, or should I manually rig the model myself? Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Edited-------
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for responding. I can only enter pose mode once I select the "rig" tab. I do not see a skeleton.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help:
[image]
Also try to enable all the layers (shortcut "~"), then press Alt+H to see everything in the scene.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I did the Alt+H I see the skeleton but its backwards.

Comment: It's not backwards. You have two rigs - the actual rig, and the metarig. Select the metarig, and move it to unused layer (M), or just hide it (H).

Comment: of course to do that you have to be in the object mode (if you're in the pose mode, press Ctrl+Tab to change it)

Answer (score 0):

Click the rig and go down where it says object mode... click pose mode and try to move the rig… prehaps that will work...

Comment: Thanks for responding. I can only do that when I select the "rig" option. Is that normal?

Answer (score 0):

I just made bones for it myself. I dont know if it was made with a better version than mines.[image]